# Storing cookies at the domain and subdomain level, who can access what?

Tags: security, cookies

I have a website that will have customers logging into:

```
www.example.com/login
```

and will do their authenticated tasks here

```
www.example.com/dashboard/
```

Customers will also have their own public facing content here:

```
customer1.example.com
```

The public facing content is where they can't write their own content, so I am concerned if they write some javascript etc. to grab cookie information somehow i.e. they write javascript, and when a different user goes to their site who was authenticated on www.example.com, the javascript will grab their session cookie and send it over to another website.

When cookies are stored at the root domain and sub-domain, are they free accessible at each level?

Trying to understand the security implications.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies will be accessible for all subdomains of the *host* you specify in the `Domain` attribute.

If you set `Domain=example.com`, the cookies will be available to all subdomains of `example.com`.

A cookie with `Domain=www.example.com` will only be accessible for `www.example.com` and subdomains of `www.example.com` (e.g. `foo.bar.www.example.com`) - no worries if you do that.
However, note that this also means it won't be accessible from `example.com`.

The most restrictive option is to omit the `Domain` attribute, by not sending it at all. In that case, the cookie should only be accessible for the hostname that sent it. That is, if you send it from `www.example.com`, it will only be sent back to `www.example.com` and not even to its subdomains.

This is all explained in [RFC 6265, section 4.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3).